How could I contact the Betriebsrat (Works Council) of my employer behind his back?
I had never in my life any contact with a Works Council (Betriebsrat) in Germany. I want to change that.
I think, already the information what they have - what is going on with the company, and inside the management - can be unthinkably valuable, also their tips and tricks, for example for the case of some power misuse or impeding layoff.
Obviously this is not something what an employer would really like. And I think, I would do better if I would not use any workplace channel to contact them. I would not even search for them on the company network. I never mention that they exist. But they are quite closely in my mind. I want to help them as I can, and I want their help if I need it.
However, the problem is that I simply have no way to find them. My only way to find them would be that I silently ask co-workers from which I think, they might be a member. Or maybe I could search for them on the company network, leaving traces. Both of them are risky.
How to find them? Do I see it well, I have all the reason to be so careful?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You make it sound like a Betriebsrat is some kind of behind the scenes shadow organisation, the underground network of cloak and dagger workers.
They are not secret at all.
They have their own laws with more than a hundred paragraphs: https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/betrvg/, detailing who they are, what they do and what privileges they have, what privileges you have, to not be discriminated against by interacting with them. They are not a shadow organization, they are determined by a free and fair election of all workers on company time. They are more public and open than probably any other function in your company. There are a hundred paragraphs on how they have to function. Chances are, there are exactly zero paragraphs in law, how the company picked your boss, or how your boss has to function.
If your company has a Betriebsrat, who is on it should be blindingly obvious to you. They should have official consultation hours, where they are available and you can go talk to them on your paid working time.
If that is not the case, your company might simply not have a Betriebsrat. Or they are really bad at their job. Criminally so, given that this is their right but also their responsibility by law.
Interacting with a Betriebsrat normally does not have any stigma attached. It depends on what you want from them or what you want them to do. They have power over many decisions and sometimes you have to consult with them, even if you are firmly on the employer's side of the argument. Sometimes you even have to consult them by law, whether you want that or not.
Please note that many times, interactions between employer and Betriebsrat can be highly politicized and/or transactional. Whatever you want from them will be treated as a bargaining chip. See What to do if your improvements are blocked for political reasons? for a perfect example what it feels like to try to get a change that is an improvement for both employer and workers through a Betriebsrat that is focused on transactional politics instead of the greater good for the company and its workers.
Even if you are going into an interview where you are not yet part of the company and they have no legal obligation to disclose all this to you, you can still just directly ask whether they have a Betriebsrat. It very much depends on how you ask. Personally, I always tell the interviewers that I ask because I did not really like what the Betriebsrat did in my old company, and want to get a feel for how things are done here. So the new employer can feel like I'm on their side, while any Betriebsrats members, should they have a say in my hiring, can just tell themselves that they are surely better than those people in my old company. As far as I know, this was never seen as a negative.

Yes, collective representation of workers interests, information sharing, that looks exactly like a hooded dagger cult with the eyes of a boss, and I do not want to look like that in his eyes. As I was hired, HR said to me, they also "need to talk with the BR but it is only a formality". He understood it so, that the BR could actually prevent my hiring, but in practice they never do. One thing is that I can consult with them in paid work time, and that my boss can not officially oppose it, but I would prefer if he would not even know it. They exist and I found their lead on Xing. Thanks!

Please note that for the same reason they are not as secretive as you think, you may also not get from them what you desire. For example, they have to be consulted by the employer in case of layoffs, but they have the same responsibilities as any other employee, so they will never be able to talk to you about layoff, until after the fact to tell you how they fought for you and tried to make the layoff as painless and fair as possible (in their eyes). Anything else would be a breach of trust on their side that would invalidate all their special protections and get them fired real fast.

@GraySheep Note that the statement  "need to talk with the BR but it is only a formality" is an accurate representation of the situation. The BR is legally required to confirm all hirings but the reasons why they may refuse to do so are explicitely listed in the law. Essentially it is things like 'the company tried to hire the totally unqualified cousin of the CEO' or 'the candidate was chosen because they offered sexual favors to the hiring manager'. If a BR refuses to confirm a hiring that is generally a sign of a major screwup of the employer.

@nvoigt Thanks. And, can they say, am I in danger? Already that helps a lot, where to focus my time: to search for my next job, or to maximize my work Leistung. Another important thing, can they help to solve conflicts with equal-level employee? Thing looks like here except that they have no reason to hate me, still they do, I have no idea why.

@GraySheep a BR could definitely help with taking complaints anonymously, while providing a potentially good opportunity for guiding you in the right direction for sorting out disputes. Each BR and what they choose to be hands-on with and not are different though, and there are definitely ones that are minimal, ones that are very hands on, ones that side mainly with management, one that side mainly with employees (a BR should aim to be a bridge between the two), etc. You can only find out by asking around. They cannot tell you if you're in danger of being fired.

@GraySheep "can they say, am I in danger?" No, they cannot. They cannot discuss anything confidential with you any more than your boss can. They can support you, once you have been made aware of it through proper channels, but while they are in the loop about who gets layed off before the fact, they cannot talk about it until it gets public.

Your link does not work for me, but yes, the BR can assist you in conflict with other workers. It doesn't have any special powers, the specific person that gets tasked with it may or may not be better suited or skilled as anyone from the normal management chain. If the normal management chain did not help, the BR might be a good option.

"If your company has a Betriebsrat, it should be blindingly obvious too you, who is on it."  - But it clearly isn't, so...
"If that is not the case, your company might simply not have a Betriebsrat. Or they are really bad at their job."  - Which seems to be the case here.

@GraySheep People often get told here that they shouldn't run to HR with interpersonal conflicts, because HR has the interests of the company at heart. I think you should be careful with the Betriebsrat for a similar reason. They have the interests of the workers as a collective at heart, not so much the interests of an individual against that collective. So if your problem is that you don't fit in socially, I wouldn't automatically assume the Betriebsrat to be on your side.
